# Programmatically setting UITabBarController's viewControllers and selectedIndex results in no selected UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a weird bug in both iOS 6 and 7 with the following `UITabBarController` subclass code:

```
self.viewControllers = @[self.myKitchenNavigationController,
                         self.photosIndexNavigationController,
                         self.postNavigationController,
                         self.feedNavigationController,
                         self.talkNavigationController];

self.selectedIndex = 0;
// self.selectedViewController = self.myKitchenNavigationController; // This doesn't help either
```

If I programmatically set `viewControllers` (previously `nil`) and immediately set a `selectedIndex` then the tab bar appears with no selection.

I had the impression that setting a selected index just after modifying the controllers was somehow "too" soon, so I wrapped that call inside a `dispatch_async` call:

```
// Fix selection by dispatching async
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
    self.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

<s>Now it works</s>, but I wonder if this is a SDK long-standing bug.

---

Actually the bug is still there, the full method:

```
- (void)setMode:(RootViewControllerMode)mode
{
    if (_mode == mode)
        return;

    NBULogInfo(@"%@ %d", THIS_METHOD, mode);

    _mode = mode;

    switch (mode)
    {
        case RootViewControllerLoggedMode:
        {
            self.viewControllers = @[self.myKitchenNavigationController,
                                     self.photosIndexNavigationController,
                                     self.postNavigationController,
                                     self.feedNavigationController,
                                     self.talkNavigationController];

            // Fix selection by dispatching async
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
            {
                self.selectedIndex = 0;
            });

            // Adjust post button
            self.postButtonHidden = NO;
            [self.view addSubview:self.postButton];
            break;
        }
        case RootViewControllerNotLoggedMode:
        {
            self.viewControllers = nil;

            // Remove post button to tabBar
            [self.postButton removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
        default:
        case RootViewControllerEmptyMode:
        {
            self.viewControllers = nil;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the only code that touches the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` and the current selected tab.

Already verified this was called on the main thread, then also tried wrapping everything inside `dispatch_async` in the main queue, and finally tried `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()`, and still the problem persists.

Comment: where are you setting "`self.viewControllers`" in your UITabBarController subclass?

Comment: Inside a `- (void)setMode:(RootViewControllerMode)mode` property that gets called by a modal login controller just before getting dismissed on successful login, thus well after all views and controllers have been loaded.

Comment: I guess you are setting `viewcontrollers` in a completion handler of login api, or in a delegate function that might not be running in `mainthread` and because of that the `selectedindex` didn't work, though you got correct solution by doing UI change in dispatch main thread.

Comment: Probably yes! Although it also worked with `dispatch_get_current_queue()` before I edited the question. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Well, just checked and `setMode:` is getting called from the `mainThread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the tab bar's `viewControllers` seems to be quite bug-prompt, besides the problem here also tab item badges appear sometimes behind the `selectionIndicatorImage`.

We end up setting the controllers in a storyboard and avoid modifying the controller's or their order.

Answer (score 0):

```
YourAppDelegate* appDelegate = (id)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
appDelegate.yourTabBar.selectedIndex = 1;
```